# User state in Xmonad

Tags: xmonad

Is it possible to have a user state in Xmonad?

I'm using global variables right now, but I wonder if there's a proper way to do it within Xmonad. (Eg: in parsec, there's a user state, so you would use `Parser TYPE ...` where TYPE is the type of the user state and is queryable with getState, putState, and modifyState.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout states in Xmonad can be specified/modified in the [config.hs](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Config.hs) module, but Xmonad has also got [extensible states](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Mutable_state_in_contrib_modules_or_xmonad.hs) that you can implement. I would recommend you look at both. The docs on the [Haskell Extensible States](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-ExtensibleState.html) lists the module as 'unstable' but i think it's a fair while since that documentation was updated (about three years?)

The [sample] code looks something like this:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import qualified XMonad.Util.ExtensibleState as XS

data ListStorage = ListStorage [Integer] deriving Typeable
instance ExtensionClass ListStorage where
initialValue = ListStorage []

.. XS.put (ListStorage [23,42])

 (e.g.)  put :: ExtensionClass a => a -> X ()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I finished implementing it and it does work. Interestingly, I did not need to derive Typeable (doesn't seem to be necessary).

Comment: Happy to help... From the brackets I think the derivable type is optional.. glad you got sorted :) by the way I just woke up, it's 6am in Ireland, thus the late reply ! ;)